# Why I cannot start delayed_job daemon with crontab?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, cron, reboot

I have the following script for starting a delayed job worker in ruby on rails

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemon_spawn'
$: << '.'

RAILS_ROOT = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..'))

class DelayedJobWorker < DaemonSpawn::Base
  def start(args)
    ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= args.first || 'development'
    Dir.chdir RAILS_ROOT
    require File.join('config', 'environment')

    Delayed::Worker.new.start
  end

  def stop
    system("kill `cat #{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid`")
  end
end

DelayedJobWorker.spawn!(:log_file => File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "log", "delayed_job.log"),
                    :pid_file => File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'tmp', 'pids', 'delayed_job.pid'),
                    :sync_log => true,
                    :working_dir => RAILS_ROOT)
```

It starts with this command

```
user@mysystem:path/to/my/application$ ruby script/delayed_job start production
DelayedJobWorker started.
```

I am trying to make this operation automatic at the startup with crontab
To do so I have made this script

```
#!/bin/bash
cd path/to/my/application
ruby script/delayed_job start production
```

and this is my crontab

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
SHELL=/bin/bash
@reboot /path/to/my/script/delayed_job_at_startup.sh
```

When I reboot the system the script does not succeed and I get this message from crontab

```
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/bash>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/finalsayan>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=finalsayan>

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- daemon_spawn (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from script/delayed_job:24:in `<main>'
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that for using cron with rvm you have lo load the rvm environment
for documentation see https://rvm.io/integration/cron/
The script that is called by cron at the startup is the following

```
#!/bin/bash
source /usr/local/rvm/environments/default

# Go to the app
APP_HOME=/path/to/my/application
cd $APP_HOME

# start the delayed jobs
ruby script/delayed_job start production
```